# Crystal report not showing data from datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have this datagridview that sends data to the database and a datatable which has a query that selects those data somehow the Crystal report that is using that datatable does not show the data from the database

Here is the code for my button:

```
private void btnpurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {             
    double cash;
    double change;
    double totalprice;
    double discount;
    double overalltotal;

    totalprice = double.Parse(txttotal.Text);
    discount = double.Parse(txtsenior.Text);
    cash = double.Parse(txtcash.Text);

    overalltotal = totalprice - discount;

    change = cash - overalltotal;
    txtchange.Text = change.ToString();
    txttotal.Text = overalltotal.ToString();

    Print f2 = new Print();
    CrystalReport1 cr = new CrystalReport1();

    TextObject text = (TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["Text4"];
    TextObject text2 = (TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["Text5"];
    TextObject text3 = (TextObject)cr.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["Text6"];
    text.Text = txtcash.Text;
    text2.Text = txttotal.Text;
    text3.Text = txtchange.Text;          

    f2.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;

    f2.Show();
 }
```

and here are the images

[This is my datatable which has a query selecting the required data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl8WO.png)

[This is my design for my crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZgmv.png)

[This is a data from my datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xijb.png)

[This is from the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHgrB.png)

[This is the preview of the crystal report without that data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQP9X.png)

Comment: But every report has a dataset, i does not see any logic where you have provided that dataset to the report.

Comment: What do you mean by that? is this what you mean `dataset1 ds = new dataset1(); `? @MuhammadWaqasAziz .. I still don't know why it will not display the data from the datable

Comment: You retrieve data from database and put it in list or dataset and then pass it to report, and you have not done it in your code

Comment: is there any option like f2.crystalReportViewer1.localreport.dataset or some thing

Comment: the main issue in your code is that you are not providing the data to the report, IS there any option like cr.Parameters.add

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz the `f2.crystalReportViewer1.localreport.dataset` the localreport doesnt exist. the `cr.Parameters.add`

Comment: I mostly worked on rdlc reports let me check on crystal report.

Comment: Here is the tutorial to design and display data in crystal report https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/index.htm
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/create-crystal-report-step-by-step-using-sql-database-view/

Comment: I tried the dataset on a different datagridview and it displayed the data as intended .. im still confused as to why the same dataset that is used on the crystal report doesn't display the data

Comment: Your dataset name and reports dataset name must be the same

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754037/Bind-Crystal-Reports-with-Dataset-or-Datatable) that may help.  This is a simple example that shows how to create and fill your dataset and then bind it to your report.

Comment: on the topic of this have you guys encountered any problem regarding printing a receipt using crystalreportviewer that it keeps printing blank endlessly after you press print?